# How to download file and save to Azure WebApp's hard disk by WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I have a web app with api what will read search engine's indexing files and return search result. Those indexing files will be updated to Blob Storage every day.

I want to make a web job. This web job will download all indexing files and save to web app hard disk.

I have reseached Microsoft's document, but cannot find anything.
Can I make this by Azure Web Job?

Comment: Can you share your code in the question?

Comment: @DasariKamali Sorry, I have not any code. I am rearching now. And this is an infra's question. And I think that if have code, they are some simple `System.IO` code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a background scheduled webjob or a queue triggered webjob to download the indexing files and store it in kudu with simple File IO operations and use a blob storage in storage account to upload the files created in kudu.

It can be easily done in webjob using [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/) library.

For Kudu simply use below to create a file in base directory in your Functions class.

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myIndexedFilePathFolder", fileName);
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
fileInfo.Directory.Create();
File.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContent, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Reference to [Microsoft Learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=visual-studio%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli%2Cidentity-visual-studio).

So to answer your question in summary I think it is possible based on the limited information available in your question.

Since we don't have much background context or information the best approach I think for you is to setup a sample project and see if this fits your requirements.